# How to parse tokens from a known URL format?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I have a string in *PHP* which reflects the *URL* routing format chosen for a website - which builds content dynamically based on the indexes / directives passed in the scheme.  For example, a typical request format may look like:

```php
$str = '/something-new/:id/goto/:new_id/full/page/:num/';
```

The data I would like to extract are the entity names for each index which are always preceded by a colon `:`.  I'm unsure however of the best approach to take - *"splitting"* the string seems cumbersome.  What would be the simplest approach to getting this resulting data into an array?

```php
$arr = [
    [0] => 'id', 
    [1] => 'new_id', 
    [2] => 'num'
];
```

Comment: Use `explode` to make an array, `array_filter` to keep the ones beginning with `:`, and `array_map` to remove the `:` character.

Comment: Or explode, then a `foreach` loop that copies the elements beginning with `:` to the result array, removing the `:` while it does so.

Comment: `preg_match_all` of course.

Comment: I don't know, but I think `:foo` are meant as the named parameters in prepared statements SQL wise, and aren't included in the *actual* URL. This is *just* a guess, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('~:(.*?)/~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

[**: demo**](http://ideone.com/i3wGrK)

Comment: Simplest and exactly what I need!

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/regular_expressions.png :-P

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but:

```
$str = '/something-new/:id/goto/:new_id/full/page/:num/';
$arr = explode('/', $str);
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($element) {
    return strpos($element, ':') === 0;
 });
$arr = array_values($arr);
$arr = array_map(function($element) {
    return substr($element, 1);
}, $arr);
```

results in:

```
$arr = array([0] => 'id', [1] => 'new_id', [2] => 'num');
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to match only alphabetical characters after `:` like this:

```
$str = '/something-new/:id/goto/:new_id/full/page/:num/';
preg_match_all("/:[a-zA-Z_]*/", $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches[0]);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => :id
    [1] => :new_id
    [2] => :num
)
```

So then just roll through `$matches[0]` to then get the final array:

```
$str = '/something-new/:id/goto/:new_id/full/page/:num/';
preg_match_all("/:[a-zA-Z_]*/", $str, $matches);
if (!empty($matches[0])) {
  $arr = array();
  foreach ($matches[0] as $match_key => $match_value) {
    $arr[] = preg_replace('/:/', '', $match_value);
  }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

So the values of `$arr` are now this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => new_id
    [2] => num
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a regex with named patterns such as:

```
~^/something-new/(?<id>[^/]+)/goto/(?<new_id>[^/]+)/full/page/(?<num>.*)$~
```

and [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match).

**Example**:

```
<?php
  $url = '/something-new/123/goto/321/full/page/1337';

  if (preg_match('~^/something-new/(?<id>[^/]+)/goto/(?<new_id>[^/]+)/full/page/(?<num>.*)$~', $url, $match)) {
    var_dump( $match['id'] , $match['new_id'] , $match['num'] );
  }
?>
```

**Output**:

```
string(3) "123"
string(3) "321"
string(4) "1337"
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/82942)

**Edit**:

From my comment, to make sure that you know that this will call them `:123` and `:321` etc. if there's actual colons in the URL;

> I don't know, but I think :foo are meant as the named parameters in prepared statements SQL wise, and aren't included in the actual URL. This is just a guess, though.